# Genymotion Google Nexus 6P 7.0.0 with Open_Gapps arm 7.0.0

Tags: android, genymotion, android-7.0-nougat

With **Genymotion 2.8.0**, I have installed **Google Nexus 6P 7.0.0** device with API level 24. After launching the device, I have flashed the ARM Virtual translator and restarted the device. Then, I have download open_gapps from http://opengapps.org/?download=true&arch=arm64&api=7.0&variant=pico for playstore and other apps installation. By drag and dropping the open_gapps zip file into the device, it is getting copied to the SDcard download folder and not installing the google apps.

Please anyone suggest me where went wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try [this](http://androiding.how/android-6-0-marshmallow-gapps/)

Comment: I have the same problem. Other apps don't run, even though I already flashed ARM Virtual translator. not just Gapps.

Comment: same issue to me.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Looking at the log files I can see it throws some error messages while determining which recovery is installed. I've tried commenting that part of the installer but it doesn't lead to other result.

Comment: Update: I got this working using the Jan 24th OpenGapps x86 package. That one flashes just fine. Seems there's been an update to the OpenGapps package that Genymotion doesn't appreciate.

Answer (score 31):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Since Genymotion 2.10 Google Play Service and Play Store can be automatically installed.

Here is the news from [Genymotion 2.10 – Seamlessly install Google Play Services and Play Store](https://www.genymotion.com/blog/2-10-open-gapps-widget/):

> Genymotion 2.10 is out! And it comes with a 1-click installer for Google Apps
>
> Simply download and install Genymotion 2.10 and a new “Open GApps” widget will be available in your toolbar. Click it and it’ll do the rest!
>
> Now you can have your applications relying on Google Play Services and Google Play Store working perfectly fine. No more fumbling around with random zip files and tutorials found there and there!

You can found the toolbar on the upper right of  genymotion shown in this image:

[image]

---

**OLD ANSWER**

There is **official FAQ** for using Google Play in [How do I install Google Play Services?](https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#google-play-services), here the FAQ text:

> For intellectual property reasons, Google Play Services are not
>   included by default in Genymotion virtual devices. However, if you
>   really need them, you can use the packages provided by OpenGapps.
>   Simply follow these steps:
>
> 1. Visit [opengapps.org](http://opengapps.org/)
> 2. Select x86 as platform
> 3. Choose the Android version corresponding to your virtual device
> 4. Select nano as variant
> 5. Download the zip file
> 6. Drag & Drop the zip installer in new Genymotion virtual device (2.7.2 and above only)
> 7. Follow the pop-up instructions
>
> > Please note Genymobile Inc. and Genymotion assume no liability
> >     whatsoever resulting from the download, install and use of Google Play
> >     Services within your virtual devices. You are solely responsible for
> >     the use and assume all liability related thereto. Moreover, we
> >     disclaim any warranties of any kind for a particular purpose regarding
> >     the compatibility of the OpenGapps packages with any version of
> >     Genymotion.

Comment: My device get's stuck flashing. Any help?

Comment: I have never once been able to get this working. I have wasted so much time on this. The file gets "successfully copied" and then nothing... I would kill for some pop up instruction like the instructions above say is suppose to happen.

Comment: Once you successfully copy the file (after a dialog contains something like "this is flashable zip..."), you need to restart the virtual device.

Comment: If you want **Maps**, you'll need to choose **mini**

Answer (score 3):

Same Issue I faced when tried to install both ARM & ARM64. May be they are not valid Gapps configured for Genymotion. But I tried my luck with '**gapps-L-4-21-15.zip**' and it worked as expected. Some tweaks still needed with play services. Yet Play store and Maps working great. I hope it may work for you too.
**Download from :** 
https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=96042739161891406