# Google Play Services on Genymotion emulator with Android 7

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, genymotion, android-7.0-nougat

I have purchased Genymotion with the goal to have a simulation with Android 7.0 and Google Play.

Android 7.0 runs fine on Genymotion, but I am not able to install Google Play on it.

Google Play works fine for Android 6.0 and below - I was able to find the sources (Flashes) that must be installed additionally for using Google Play in Genymotion.

Does someone know how to install Google Play on an Android 7.0 Device with Genymotion?

Comment: did you try to install ARM translation and then nougat gapps?

Comment: I installed the translation, but I am not able to install the apps. When drag drop the the zip, nothing happens, but the message zip file successfully tranferred. No automatically flash started. Where do I find the official virusfree flashes ?

Comment: it means that it is not a flashable zip,download a zip from http://opengapps.org/ , use ARM platform and coresponding Android version

Comment: Apk mirror has viruses?

Comment: I don't know, I just was on sites, that didn't give me a good feeling :-) Where do I find the official translation zip file ?

Comment: @mayosk I thought Genymotion runs Androidx86 through VirtualBox

Comment: that's why you need to flash ARM translation, therefore you can flash ARM zips on genymotion

Comment: @mayosk Those zip files aren't flashable, though. Have you tried it? https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/issues/135

Comment: I tried it, but on lollipop where it worked,so if those zips aren't flashable, just find try to flash another one, ex. https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/gapps-dynamic-gapps-t3487192

Comment: @mcflysoft : The whole process is now AUTOMATIC! Please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765915/google-play-services-on-genymotion-emulator-with-android-7/46725748#46725748) down here ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

***Updated answer***
Since Genymotion 2.10, you are able to install `Google Play Services` within ease without dealing with zip files. You now have a `1-click installer` (called `"Open GApps" widget`).

Here are few notes to consider:

- The `1-click installer` is available for every device running Android 4.4 or more (whether new or already created), as long as Genymotion 2.10 is installed.
- The `Open GApps` widget installs the smallest variant (i.e. `pico`) as it fits most development and testing needs.
  That means you only get `Google Play Store` and `Google Play Services` and nothing else.

If you need access to further Google apps, you can either visit the `Play Store` and download them from there or you can install another variant of `Open GApps` from their website, as describe in my original answer.

**How to use the widget and install `Open GApps`**
Just open your Genymotion device.
You will see a gray `Open GApps` logo on the right bar, alongside with all the other settings:

[image: Unused Open GApps widget]

When you click on that logo, Genymotion will start downloading `Open GApps` to your device:

[image: Downloading Open GApps]

Then, you will need to restart your device and you're all set:

[image: Instalation Seccusfull]

---

***Original answer***
In order to install Google Play and use it on Genymotion, you will need to find a zip file of the pre-built Google Apps packages to onto the emulator.

As mentioned in the comments to your question, Genymotion's ROM is compiled to x86 to match the most popular computer's CPU architecture.
However, most of the pre-built Google Apps packages available are using ARM architecture, which is popular among phones.
Some of the comments mentioned the need for installing an `ARM Translation` which will let those ARM apps to run on the x86 virtual device, but it might be difficult to find the right translation file for Android Nougat *and anyway that it not necessary at all*.

You are able to go to the [open GApps site](http://opengapps.org/) and install the needed pre-built Google Apps packages that you desire.
Make sure to choose ***`Platform: x86`*** and the proper Android version.

In order to install it on Genymotion just drag and drop the zip file into the emulator and you will be prompted with the following message which lets you know that the file can be flashed to the device:
[image: Flashing openGApps on Genymotion emulator]
Click `OK` and it will flash the file.
When the process is done you will be prompted with the following message:
[image: Flashing process onto Genymotion emulator is done]
All you need to do is to restart the device emulator and you will have Google Play on your Android Nougat emulator.
Enjoy.

Comment: FYI, Genymotion has now automated this process with a 'one button click' procedure! Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765915/google-play-services-on-genymotion-emulator-with-android-7/46725748#46725748

Comment: if you unable to see that icon click on more icon(down arrow) you can see there open GAaps

Answer (score 19):

Since Genymotion 2.10, **Gapps can be installed automatically from within Genymotion**!

Top right of the Genymotion emulator window, you will find a **'Gapps' button**: click on it and Genymotion will do the rest: downloading the correct GApps bundle and install it in your Android image!

Once installed, just restart this emulator: the Gapps button **now have a green check mark** on it and the Open Gapps (Pico) bundle has been installed for the specific version of Android you are running :-)

Works for Android 4.4 onwards.

Read more at 
https://www.genymotion.com/blog/2-10-open-gapps-widget/

Comment: wow...never saw that button !  THIS IS THE BEST ANSWER BY FAR.  Not sure why there are not more upvotes.   I've been struggling for years with other solutions, can't believe it is this easy now.  Sick.

Comment: @daticon yeah, I was also totally blown away when I discovered that! Good for us :-)

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

As @pascal pointing out (kudos to @pascal), since Genymotion 2.10 Google Play Service and Play Store can be automatically installed.

Here is the news from [Genymotion 2.10 – Seamlessly install Google Play Services and Play Store](https://www.genymotion.com/blog/2-10-open-gapps-widget/):

> Genymotion 2.10 is out! And it comes with a 1-click installer for Google Apps
>
> Simply download and install Genymotion 2.10 and a new “Open GApps” widget will be available in your toolbar. Click it and it’ll do the rest!
>
> Now you can have your applications relying on Google Play Services and Google Play Store working perfectly fine. No more fumbling around with random zip files and tutorials found there and there!

---

**OLD ANSWER**

Quoting myself from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40712778/4758255:

There is **official FAQ** for using Google Play in [How do I install Google Play Services?](https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#google-play-services), here the FAQ text:

> For intellectual property reasons, Google Play Services are not
>   included by default in Genymotion virtual devices. However, if you
>   really need them, you can use the packages provided by OpenGapps.
>   Simply follow these steps:
>
> 1. Visit [opengapps.org](http://opengapps.org/)
> 2. Select x86 as platform
> 3. Choose the Android version corresponding to your virtual device
> 4. Select nano as variant
> 5. Download the zip file
> 6. Drag & Drop the zip installer in new Genymotion virtual device (2.7.2 and above only)
> 7. Follow the pop-up instructions
>
> > Please note Genymobile Inc. and Genymotion assume no liability
> >     whatsoever resulting from the download, install and use of Google Play
> >     Services within your virtual devices. You are solely responsible for
> >     the use and assume all liability related thereto. Moreover, we
> >     disclaim any warranties of any kind for a particular purpose regarding
> >     the compatibility of the OpenGapps packages with any version of
> >     Genymotion.

Comment: This worked for me and was simple. After multiple attempt at flashing many things and following different SO answers. Worked with a API 23 (Android 6.0) genymotion device. Thanks!

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך The link you included works. But, when I actually try to download the zip file, I get a 404 error message from Github. I have tried on several browsers.

Comment: Maybe a glitch from GitHub in your region. I'm trying to download one of the file and it works.

Comment: FYI, Genymotion introduced a new method that just requires one click! check me answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765915/google-play-services-on-genymotion-emulator-with-android-7/46725748#46725748