# Can I install Google Play Services and the Play Store without using Gapps?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, genymotion

I've been searching the internet and working for about 3 hours on on my Nexus 5 (5.1.0 API 22) Genymotion emulator. I have followed multiple guides, and none of them are working when it comes to flashing the Gapps. The ARM-translation works, and so does the PlayServices.apk (albeit I cannot reboot through the shell using either "adb rebbot" or "adb shell reboot"). But when I try to install Gapps (micro 5.1 ARM) on my emulator, it fails to flash "for an unknown reason". I've tried uninstalling Genymotion, removing all the leftover files, and uninstalling Virtualbox as well. Can anyone help? I'm going out of my mind trying to fix this.

Comment: Please see this answer for further details on how to flash `GApps` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41864232/6253504

Answer (score 1):

So I eventually figured out that although the Nexus 5 is technically ARM, the emulator requires x86 framework. So any other poor souls who find their way here- download x86 APKs, not ARM!